# div height is not growing according to content size

Tags: php, css, html, styles

Hi I have a dynamic content `$search_results` and I am trying to display It inside a `<div>`. but the problem is the the height of the `<div>` is not increasing according to the content size. `$search_results` is a tabled content like `<table><tr><td>Values</td></tr></table>`

and here is the code.

```
<div  style="background:#CCC;">
<div style="height:500px;width:1000px;margin:auto;padding-top:20px;">
<div style="width:200px;float:left; background:#666;color:white;">
<form name="SearchForm" action="" method="post">
<ul class="SearchList">
<li class="firstlist">Search</li>

<li>
   <input  type="text"  class="text_medium" value="Keywords" name="KeywordsTextBox" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Keywords'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Keywords' ) this.value=''" >
</li>

<li>
  <select name="SearchValues" class="select_medium">
     <option value="Search1">Search option 1</option>
     <option value="Search1">Search option 2</option>
     <option value="Search1">Search option 3</option>
     <option value="Search1">Search option 4</option>
  </select>
</li>

  <input type='submit' name='SearchButton' class='Small_Button'  value='Search'>
</li>

</ul>
</form>
</div>
<div style="width:800px;float:right; background:#C69;">
<form name="ResultForm" method="post" action="">
<?php 

//$serachObj =  new Search()

//$search_results = $serachObj->search();

echo $search_results; 
?>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried `style="min-height:500px;"` but its not working. Any suggestions ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is **float** in your the child `DIV's`. So, you have to clear the it's parent. Define **overflow:hidden** to the parent DIV. For example write like this:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;min-height:500;width:1000px;margin:auto;padding-top:20px;">
 <div style="float:left"></div>
 <div style="float:left"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED**

```
<div style="min-height:500;width:1000px;margin:auto;padding-top:20px;">
     <div style="float:left"></div>
     <div style="float:left"></div>
     <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: On which div or need to create new..?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Read this for more http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Comment: But min-height is not working I think.. when I search its fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:auto` to the parent div

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b9kVC/)**

Answer (score 1):

Give div height as auto.

```
height:auto;
```

Comment: <div style="height:500px;width:1000px;margin:auto;padding-top:20px;">